# Unable to create OpportunityLineItem objects while unit testing the code

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I have a Controller extension on Opportunity object that I am trying to test using unit tests. The code (see below), inserts all the data appropriately in the database. However when I try to print to see how many Opportunity Line Items are there for the given opportunity, I get 0. Any Idea what I may be missing?

I've not included helper methods to create test data in this posting

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
public class TestOpportunityLineItemExt {
    public static testMethod void testOpporunityLineItemCtrl() {

    // Set up test data

        Opportunity opp = createOpportunity('03', false);        
        PriceBook2 pb2 = [Select id from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true limit 1];
        Product2 prd = createProduct2(pb2);        
       PriceBookEntry pbe = createPriceBookEntry(pb2, prd);

       // Create OpportunityLineItem with Opportunity.id
        createOppotunityLineItem(pbe, opp);

        // End of setting up data 


        // Work with Actual tests
        Test.startTest();

        PageReference pageRef = Page.pageName;

        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
       // OpportunityLineItmeExt is Controller extention for Opportunity;
      // with a constructor that takes Opportunity as a parameter
      OpportunityLineItemExt ctrl = new OpportunityLineItemExt(opp);

        List <OpportunityLineItem> itList = opp.OpportunityLineItems;
        // This should print actual number of records inserted, but prints 0
        ********* System.debug('-------------- Total count of oli ' + itList.size());
        Test.stopTest();            
    }



    public static void createOpportunityLineItem(PriceBookEntry pbe, Opportunity opp) {
        // now create opportunity line item        
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++) {            
            OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
            oli.opportunityid = opp.id;
            oli.unitPrice = 20000;
            oli.quantity = 100 * (i + 1);
            oli.PriceBookEntryId = pbe.id;
            insert oli;
            System.debug('---------- Inserted ' + oli.id + ' ' + oli.quantity + ' opp id ' + opp.id);
        }    
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the attribute seeAllData=true and also you have a DML operation in you for loop in the method createOpportunityLineItem

Comment: wihtou seeAllData=true, I was not able to get standard pricebook2. I've a query in one of the helper methods (not included in this code snippet)... PriceBook2 pb2 = [Select id from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true limit 1];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to query the child OpportunitylineItems out of the DB after they are inserted. The `opp` Opportunity variable does not automatically contain all of its child lists. They must be queried explicitly.
Calling your constructor does not automatically query the children for you.

You have

```
Opportunity opp = createOpportunity('03', false);
```

Then you insert the OpportunityLineItems and then you try to access the children directly on the `opp` variable.

```
opp.OpportunityLineItems
```

Instead, you need to query the Opportunity again and include the children OpportunityLineItems.  Something like:

```
Opportunity oppWithLines = [
   Select Amount, CloseDate, Name, 
        (Select TotalPrice,  UnitPrice,  ListPrice 
        From OpportunityLineItems) 
   From Opportunity 
   Where Id = :opp.Id
];

System.debug(oppWithLines.OpportunityLineItems.size());
```

Comment: Hi Peter,  Thanks for your help. Your suggestion worked like a charm. Thanks again.